# C# - WCF works on local machine, but not over network

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, wcf

I have a problem with my WCF in a C# appliction. I am able to call the Service when server and client are on the same PC, but i get a timeout on the request if server and client are on different PCs.
I have opened the ports in the firewall (I use port 9998) and I even tried to shut the firewall down.
The *app.config* of the server looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SMS_ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SMS_ServiceBehavior" name="SMSapplication.SMS_Service">
        <endpoint address="http://10.20.5.100:9998/SMS_Service" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" name="SMS_ServiceEndpoint" contract="SMSapplication.ISMS_Service" />
        <endpoint address="http://10.20.5.100:9998/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone please have an idea what else I could try or where the error could be?

Comment: Is that really the _public_ IP address of your server machine? (You should reconsider publishing it here ... )

Comment: Try increasing the timeout value. Maybe your operation takes longer over the network than it took when working within one machine.

Comment: Are you able to ping that IP from the client machine? Can you share the config file of the client application too?

Comment: The ip address works, I am able to ping the machine and I am also able to call the port with telnet.

Answer (score 0):

The config file of the client looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="SMS_ServiceEndpoint" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:9998/SMS_Service" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="SMS_ServiceEndpoint" contract="SMS_Service.ISMS_Service"
                name="SMS_ServiceEndpoint" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: your client references to localhost => it should reference to your server ip

Answer (score 0):

I take care in the code by following:

```
SMS_Service.SMS_ServiceClient client = new SMS_Service.SMS_ServiceClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://10.20.5.100:9998/SMS_Service"), client.Endpoint.Address.Identity, client.Endpoint.Address.Headers);
client.Open();
client.DoWork("test");
client.Close();
```